# how do I write a query to select element that has a tag id in an array of tag ids with SQL?

Tags: sql, arrays, presto

I am trying to create an SQL query using PRESTO DATABASE to get ticket numbers that have a tag applied. The tags are in the ticket_tag column but the ticket tag column's rows each have an array of all tag ids the ticker has. I want to scan the array and verify that the tag id I am looking for is in it so I can select or return only those ticket numbers. Can someone help?

all_tickets_tags looks like this:

```
[999170833505476,12403428395,12706673982,104100556289383,202231716456598,430869490433479,605189679499805,928941873813160]
```

they are tag id's.

```
SELECT ticker_number, ticket_tags
FROM ticket_activity
WHERE all_ticket_tags = 513515886108503
```

Comment: This question leaves a lot open. What DBMS are you using? What's the actual schema? What does the actual data look like? What is your expected result? What have you tried already and what's the problem with that? [Edit] the question and provide a [example].

Comment: Anyway, consider normalizing the schema and don't store arrays in a column. Use a linking table.

Comment: "ticket tag column's rows each have an array of all tag ids the ticker has."  Very curious.  SQL does not support arrays, in general, although some databases do extend the language.

Comment: Are you referring to this [PRESTO](https://aws.amazon.com/big-data/what-is-presto/)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [contains](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/array.html#contains) function.

```sql
contains(all_ticket_tags, 513515886108503)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the array is just a string you can match with a SQL LIKE statement.

```
...
WHERE all_ticket_tags LIKE '%tag%'
```

Alternatively and more correctly, you can [unnest the array](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/sql/select.html#unnest) or use a function like `contains` that is custom built for array structure, but it will depend on the actual format of the field in question.

Comment: The backtick should be single-quotation in Presto.

Comment: oopps .. been doing too much markdown and asciidoc writing ... fixed